# (iPhone SDK) How to modify UIButton by tag id?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I've created a group of buttons as follows:

```
NSString *nameImg;
UIButton *button;

for(int i=1;i<=144;i++){
    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posX, posY, 43, 43)];
    nameImg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i.png",i];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nameImg] forState:(UIControlState)normal];
    button.tag = i;
    [scrollView addSubview:button];

    posX += 55;

    if (i % 4 == 0){
            posY += 55;
        posX = 15;
    }
}
```

How can I modify a button getting it by tag? It's possible to do something like the following line?

```
[button.tagId setTitle:@"hello"];
```

I don't want a listener method, I only want to modify the button identifying it by tag.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[(UIButton*)[scrollView viewWithTag:tagId] setTitle:@"hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 5):

Call viewWithTag: on parent view.

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[scrollView viewWithTag:tagID];
```

Then you can make any change using btn.

Not asked in the question, you are leaking memory for button inside the loop. After adding this to scrollView you need to send release to button.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [**Key-Value Coding Programming Guide from Apple**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/DataTypes.html).